# Error on my jquery ajax json function, wont return data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Hi iv got this error on my ajax function using json on retrieving data. It wont return any data. Here's my code below

```
$.ajax({
  url: "php/getCategory.php?action=getyear",
  cache: false,
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(data){
    $.each(data.items, function(i,item){
        $("#catYear").append('<option value="'+item.id+'">'+item.name+'</option>');
    });
  }
});
```

When i try to remove dataType: "json" it will pass into success: function. I think the problem is on my json. I also echo the output of my getCategory.php and i think their is no problem on it. Below is the output of my php json_encode.

```
{items:[{"id":"1","name":"2010"},{"id":"2","name":"2011"}]}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is the PHP outputting with a JSON header?

Comment: @dotty...what do you mean by that, sorry im new on this..can you give me example. thanks!

Comment: @dotty...i im using json_encode. I think there is no need to put that on my header. Am i correct?

Comment: You should check your JSON with http://jsonlint.com/ - it isn't valid.

Comment: `json_encode` will give you a lump of JSON. You still need the to say `header('content-type: application/json');` otherwise PHP will claim it is sending an HTML document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from jquery documentation :

Important: As of jQuery 1.4, if the JSON file contains a syntax error, the request will usually fail silently. Avoid frequent hand-editing of JSON data for this reason. JSON is a data-interchange format with syntax rules that are stricter than those of JavaScript's object literal notation. For example, all strings represented in JSON, **whether they are properties or values**, must be enclosed in double-quotes. For details on the JSON format, see http://json.org/.

so jour json string has element items which is not double quoted try something like that :

```
{"items":[{"id":"1","name":"2010"},{"id":"2","name":"2011"}]}
```

Comment: thats why this is the first time i encountered this problem. My previous version of my jquery is 1.3+. This is the first time i change into 1.4.